# When to use as_* vs to_* vs into_* in Rust?

Tags: rust, naming-conventions

My understanding, based on the standard library examples, is that:

`into_` convention is used when the function completely absorbs the ownership and spits out another type, as in `into_iter()` . Is the understanding correct?

The real confusion is between `as_` and `to_` . 
It seems `to_` as in `to_owned()` takes the reference of a type and spits a new related type (like a type coercion), where as `to_string()` takes the reference of type and spits a new type (as in type conversion).

But `as_` as in `as_ptr` also seems like type coercion. I couldn't find any examples for this beyond `as_ptr` or `as_mut`.

Can someone explain exactly the cases where we need to use the specific naming convention and with a real life example that is beyond what's used in standard library?

Comment: [Rust API Guidelines - Naming](https://rust-lang.github.io/api-guidelines/naming.html#ad-hoc-conversions-follow-as_-to_-into_-conventions-c-conv)

Comment: `to_owned` and `to_string` are not type coercion. They are often equal to `clone` and will deep copy the object in question, or otherwise allocate memory.

Comment: @PitaJ I agree, but `to_` sounds like type coercion incase of `to_owned`, infact it is not. That's where the confusion is. The API guidelines table helped a lot

Comment: Thanks @kmdreko. This link should have been part of the docs. Very much helpful

Answer (score 19, accepted):

There is a [Naming](https://rust-lang.github.io/api-guidelines/naming.html#ad-hoc-conversions-follow-as_-to_-into_-conventions-c-conv) section of the Rust API Guidelines that includes recommendations for "conversion" methods and shows a handy table:

| Prefix | Cost | Ownership |
| --- | --- | --- |
| `as_` | Free | borrowed -> borrowed |
| `to_` | Expensive | borrowed -> borrowed borrowed -> owned (non-Copy types) owned -> owned (Copy types) |
| `into_` | Variable | owned -> owned (non-Copy types) |

The guidelines continue with examples like `str::as_bytes()`, `str::to_lowercase()`, `String::into_bytes()`, etc. and some other considerations for abstraction and mutability.

A quicker way to think about it:

- if it consumes the data, use `into_*`
- if it returns another "view" of the data, use `as_*`
- otherwise use `to_*`

These rules are pretty much followed by the standard library and most ecosystem crates. As always though, these are more *guidelines* than actual rules. Conventions are helpful but don't need to have strict adherence.